# How to get top tab element id in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the id of the element I have selected in the top tab navigator I have used, but when I try, the ids of all of them, not a single item, appear in the console output, how can I access the id information of only one element? I am using below codes for top tab

```
 function setCat(id) {
  axios.get('https://localhost/api/get/parentCategory?id='+id)
  .then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
} 


function list(menu){  
  if(menu){
    return menu.map(element => {
      return (
        <TopTap.Screen key={element._id} name={element.link} initialParams={{
          id:element._id,
        }} component={ProductList} options={{
          tabBarLabel:element.name
        }} onPress={setCat(element._id)} />
      );
    });
  }
}

function MyTopTabs({navigation,route}) {
  const [product,setProduct] = React.useState();
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://localhost/api/get/category')
    .then(function (response) {
     setProduct(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <TopTap.Navigator >
      <TopTap.Screen  name="Product" component={ProductScreen} options={{tabBarLabel:'Products'}} />
      {
      
       list(product)
      }
    
    </TopTap.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem by adding tab press under listeners, you can check it from the code below

```
return menu.map(element => {
      return (
        <TopTap.Screen key={element._id} name={element.link} initialParams={{
          id:element._id,
        }} component={ProductList} options={{
          tabBarLabel:element.name
        }} listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              console.log(element._id)
              AsyncStorage.setItem('subCat', element._id);
              let bas =  AsyncStorage.getItem('subCat')
              alert(element.name)
              
            }
        }} />
      );
    });
```